# clevis/dracut luks unlocker - early dracut unlocker not engaging upon boot

Tags: boot, encryption, luks

How to get FDE unlocked by clevis early dracut unlocker?

I have installed

- Ubuntu 18 Server full disk encryption.
- clevis (from source).
- dracut (from source, to resolve clevis build dependencies)
- sudo clevis luks bind -d /dev/sda3 tpm2 '{"pcr_ids":"7"}'
- sudo dracut -f

dracut succeeds;

```
dracut: *** Including module: clevis ***
```

However, boot still waits for input upon boot, dracut unlocker seemingly not engaging:

```
"Please unlock disk sda3_crypt:"
```

(Late unlocker using systemd previously verified OK)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 18 Full Disk Encryption clevis early unlock tested successfully with the initramfs patches; https://github.com/latchset/clevis/pull/35